# How to query(getItems) for two conditions (non-existent + some value) on single attribute in DynamoDB?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to query(getItems) on DynamoDB table to find all items where the InitiateMQFlag = 0 or the 'InitiateMQFlag' attribute is not yet set. A global secondary index called BLEAdvertisement-InitiateMQFlag-index exists on the table which includes the InitiateMQFlag field. I had used FilterExpression: "attribute_not_exists(InitiateMQFlag)" but it throws me errors.

```
var params = {
        TableName: device_table,
        IndexName: "BLEAdvertisement-InitiateMQFlag-index",
        KeyConditionExpression: "BLEAdvertisement = :BLEAdvertisement AND InitiateMQFlag = :InitiateMQFlag",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ':BLEAdvertisement': BLEAdvertisements[i],
          ':InitiateMQFlag' : InitiateMQFlagValue
        },
        FilterExpression: "attribute_not_exists(InitiateMQFlag)"
      };
```

Result:

```
code:"ValidationException"
message:"Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes: Primary key attribute: InitiateMQFlag"
name:"ValidationException"
requestId:"OVIAPBSCAAU42OI41LQUSGIU7JVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG"
retryable:false
retryDelay:3.1105465830200685
statusCode:400
```

If there is another way to get the non-existent attribute with another query on single attribute, it will also help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FilterExpression` is used to relatively-inefficiently filter out results after already reading them from the partition - you'll be paying for the read before the filtering happens. DynamoDB is refusing to allow you to filter on a **primary key** (partition key or sort key) to hint you that there is a more efficient way to do this: You should use a `KeyConditionExpression` instead.

And, in your case, you are indeed doing a `KeyConditionExpression` on the key column InitiateMQFlag. So beyond the fact that it's not allowed to filter on this column, why would you even want to? Given `KeyConditionExpression` already limits the query only to items where InitiateMQFlag = :InitiateMQFlag - how can it ever match the attribute_not_exists(InitiateMQFlag) filter?